# Django flatpages and a catchall startpage

Tags: python, django, django-flatpages

I'm using django 1.1 and flatpages. It works pretty well, but I didn't manage to get a catchall or default page running.

As soon as I add a entry to url.py for my startpage, the flatpages aren't displayed anymore.

```
(r'^', 'myproject.mysite.views.startpage'),
```

I know flatpages uses a 404 hook, but how do you configure the default website?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you want (with a `$`):

```
(r'^$', 'myproject.mysite.views.startpage')
```

It should catch only empty requests.

Answer (score 2):

This regex matches everything, so no wonder that flatpages are not working - they are only fallback, activated on 404 error. And with this regex you don't give a chance for 404 error to show.

So, what you want to do is not possible with such regex catchall and flatpages.
Personally, if I want to do catch-all, I put all 'normal' URLs above it - but flatpages are not using URLs so...